# How do I see if a string contains another string with quotes in it?

Tags: c#, html, string

I am trying to see if a large string contains this line of HTML:

```
<label ng-class="choiceCaptionClass" class="ng-binding choice-caption">Was this information helpful?</label>
```

As you can see, this snippet has quotations in multiple places and it's causing problems when I do something like this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(responseContent.Contains("<label ng-class="choiceCaptionClass" class="ng - binding choice - caption">Was this information helpful?</label>"));
```

I've tried both of these ways of defining the string:

```
@"<label ng-class=""choiceCaptionClass"" class=""ng - binding choice - caption"">Was this information helpful?</label>"
```

and

```
"<label ng-class=\"choiceCaptionClass\" class=\"ng - binding choice - caption\">Was this information helpful?</label>"
```

But in each case the Contains() method looks for the literal string with either the double quotes or the backslashes.  Is there another way I could define this string so I can correctly search for it?

Comment: Try with a regularExpression

Comment: Is using [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net) out of the question?  It handles searching/parsing HTML for you.  This way you dont have to roll your own.

Comment: Very good idea, I had forgotten to use the Agility Pack.  I'll be including this in my upcoming work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escaping the double-quotes with backslashes is the proper thing to do.

The reason your search may be failing is that the strings don't actually match. For example, in your version with backslashes, you have spaces around some of the dashes but your HTML string does not.

Answer (score 1):

Try using regular expressions. I made this one for you but you can test your own regex [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester).

```
var regex = new Regex(@"<label\s+ng-class\s*=\s*""choiceCaptionClass""\s+class\s*=\s*""ng-binding choice-caption""\s*>\s*Was this information helpful\?\s*</label>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Assert.IsTrue(regex.IsMatch(responseContent));
```

If this is not working use the tester tool to figure it out what part of the pattern is getting off.

Hope this help!